# C++ Functions run no matter input

Tags: c++, function

The problem with the code below is, no matter what what the input is in the console, all the functions run as if they were true. As an example, I could input "vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv" and both "hello" and "good thank you" would output. Its as if the parameters of the functions don't matter.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

void main() 
{
void confirmChk(bool &confirm);
bool confirm = false;
void greetingChk(bool &greeting);
bool greeting = false;
void questionChk(bool &question);
bool question = false;
void youChk(bool &you);
bool you = false;
std::string text;
std::getline(std::cin, text);

    for (int read = 0; read < text.length(); read++)
    {
        greetingChk(greeting);
        if (greeting = true);
        {
            youChk(you);
            if (you = true);
                {
                    std::cout<<"hello" <<std::endl;
                }
        }
        questionChk(question);
        if (question = true);
        {
            youChk(you);
            if (you = true);
            {
                std::cout<<"good thank you" <<std::endl;
            }
        }
    std::chrono::milliseconds dura(2000);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(dura);
    system("cls");
    }
}

//////////////////Functions//////////////////
void greetingChk(bool &greeting)
{
    std::string text;
    std::getline(std::cin, text);
    if(text.find("hi ") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("hello ") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("hey ") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("yo ") != std::string::npos || 
       text.find("sup ") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("howdy ") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("wazzup ") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("hiya ") != std::string::npos)
            {
                greeting = true;
            }
    else
            { 
                greeting = false;
            }
}
void youChk(bool &you)
{
    std::string text;
    std::getline(std::cin, text);
    if(text.find("ya ") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("you ") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("yah ") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("yall ") != std::string::npos || 
       text.find("you're ") != std::string::npos)
            {
                you = true;
            }
    else
            { 
                you = false;
            }
}
void questionChk(bool &question)
{
    std::string text;
    std::getline(std::cin, text);
    if(text.find("are") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("am") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("can") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("could") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("do") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("does") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("did") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("has") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("had") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("have") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("is") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("may") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("might") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("shall") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("should") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("was") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("would") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("were") != std::string::npos)
            {
                question = true;
            }
    else
            { 
                question = false;
            }
}
void confirmChk(bool &confirm)
{
    std::string text;
    std::getline(std::cin, text);
    if(text.find("ok") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("yup") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("yes") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("affirm") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("affirmative") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("confirm") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("confirmed") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("confirming") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("endorse") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("endorsed") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("approve") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("approved") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("approving") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("of course") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("got it") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("will do") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("alright") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("fine") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("varify") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("ratify") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("validate") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("understood") != std::string::npos ||
       text.find("justify") != std::string::npos)
            {
                confirm = true;
            }
    else
            { 
                confirm = false;
            }
}
```

Comment: `=` => `==`, ugh. And it makes little sense checking for `== true`, btw.

Comment: And remove `;` in `if (greeting = true);`

Comment: use `int main()` instead of `void main()`, even if your compiler seems to accept it. Aside: Do you have compiler-warnings enabled? And do you mind them, lie at all?

Comment: I changed = to == where needed and changed void main() to in main(). Nothing outputs with irrelevant inputs which is good, but now even when parameters are met, nothing outputs. Any ideas?

Comment: Why putting forward-declarations into `main`? Also, why so many? Reorder your functions, and you need hardly any anyway. ***Please compile with full warnings enabled:*** `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. And solve them!! BTW: This Q&A-Site is not the right place to learn basic debugging.

Comment: @Deduplicator: After the changes, everything compiles with only one error. warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch ------ Just fixed this error. Replaced int read = 0 with size_t read = 0.

Comment: Although not an error, why are you declaring functions inside `main`?  Rule of thumb is that function declarations go at the top of the file or in a header file.

Comment: After you get the compilation errors fixed and the code inspection issues (as in the comments above), use a **debugger** to execute each line of your code separately.  Verify that the logic is executed correctly and the contents of the variables are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` statements have more entries then a teenage girls phone. :-)

You should invest in some structures, containers and loops.
For example:

```
const static std::string question_words[] =  
{"am", "are", "can", "did", "could", "do", "does"};
const static unsigned int word_quantity =
    sizeof(question_words) / sizeof(question_words[0]);

//...
bool is_question = false;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < word_quantity; ++i)
{
  if (text == question_word[i])
  {
    is_question = true;
    break;
  }
}
```

You can put this logic into a function, and pass it the word array and the word.  That way, you can call the function for the different word containers and not write extra code.  Your code would like like:

```
  bool is_question = false;
  is_question = Is_Word_In_Array(question_words, word_quantity, text);
  if (is_question)
  {
    cout << "sentence is a question\n";
  }
  if (Is_Word_In_Array(greeting_words, greeting_word_quantity, text))
  {
    cout << "sentence has a greeting.\n";
  }
```

If you sort the arrays, you can use existing search functions like `std::binary_search` to find your word.

Answer (score 0):

I hardly know where to begin. Your main loop executes as many times as there are characters in your input string.

All of your `if` statements *are* true, because you set them that way.

Saying
        if (greeting = true);
first sets `greeting` to `true`, and then does nothing (because of the semicolon right after the conditional clause).
The following statements within braces will be executed because they are not part of the `if`. Again, because of the semicolon after the conditional clause.

Use something more like

```
if (greeting)
{
  // conditional code here
}
```

I think you really meant `if (greeting == true)` which is the same as `if (greeting)`.

Comment: Made the changes and things are running smoother, but now I'm not getting any output at all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one of your problems: You're using the assignment operator `=` instead of the equality operator `==`. So, when you use:

```
if (greeting = true)
```

...you're saying "set greeting to true. if the results of this operation return true, then ..." What you want to use is this:

```
if (greeting == true)
```

This says "compare greeting to true. if the results of this operation return true (i.e. if they are equal), then..." However, you can actually make this a little more concise with this:

```
if (greeting)
```